# Using Cookie for Auth in Sangria

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

So there's already an example for authenticating by mutating "login" and returning the auth token as part of the response - does anyone have any ideas how I might use a secure cookie instead? I'd really strongly prefer to use this if I can, as it's an extra barrier against sessions being hijacked by an XSS attack on my relay app. I'm using Akka HTTP.

Ideas I've had so far:

- Set the token value on the context as a mutable value during query execution, then grab it out inside a `map` call (bad)
- Set the token on the response as in the example, then in a `map` call modify the response to remove the auth token and set it as a cookie instead (less bad, but not exactly great).

Is there something better than I haven't thought of?

Comment: I would suggest you to check this comment: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/407#issuecomment-234726123 Also I would suggest you to handle the login as a separate endpoint, especially if you would like to use secure cookie for it.

Comment: Yeah I've certainly considered doing auth outside of GraphQL, but it makes the resulting change to the state of my relay app a bit awkward.

I guess it'd work if I did an ajax request to login and then immediately upon that request completing, trigger a mutation in Relay that allows it to get the details for the newly logged in user and all associated state.

I'll keep playing around with it...

Answer (score 0):

A 'secure cookie" I assume you are referring to a signed cookie?
Signatures do not hide cookie contents, the contents are simply treated as being tampered if the signature failed to validate, but the cookie is public/readable anyway

If the cookie itself being present is how a session will re-auth for each subsequent request (maintain session, aka; 'session riding' in attacker speak) then it being signed or not is functionally no different than losing an 'auth token' (assume you mean an OAuth2/OIDC/JWT but not an API Key?) via XSS

So far we have discussed 'auth' in the sense of authorisation (authz), that having a token authorises you to make the request, the response trusts you are who you claim - i.e. the system of using a cookie or a token that implies this is merely a trust-based system, no real authorisation 'mechanism', only unverified trust in the cookie or token

To apply an authorisation 'mechanism' for signed cookie, or token, there must be a mechanism the server can use to verify the sender is the authentic (auth in the sense of authentication aka authn). Does your application code apply one-time authn and 'bearer' token/cookie trust without authz? Bearer authz means you have th 'thing' and if you have it you are authorised. Because Bearer authz is a blind, unverified, method of authz that if the 'thing they bear to you is stolen anyone can be a bearer and gain authz.

Or do you want to apply an authz mechanism?

If you are doing bearer only, the signed cookie or auth token is equivalent security, from the attackers perspective.

If you are interested in applying authz mechanisms so the token can be verified for authenticity, this mostly requires the requester to have a secret to 'sign' the token or cookie with, a secret they have that signing can prove they have it without sending it over the wire to the server with the request (and expose the secret).

To learn more about this start with OWASP Authz page (I contributed to) here https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html

If this is no longer relevant, please accept the answer for other readers who come across it.